# Java. Повторяющиеся символы в массиве

Tags: java

**Задача**

> Задана строка символов определенной длины. Определить новую сроку,
>   полученную после удлинения исходной на каждый встречаемый по одному
>   разу символ и переворачивания. Пример: a=”abaс” rez = “ccabba”.

Я сделал всё, кроме последнего пункта. Нужно чтобы повторяющиеся символы в строке вывелись один раз, без удвоения. А как это сделать не знаю

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainFive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите строку:");
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        int ln = str.length();
        char[] chars= str.toCharArray();

        for (int i=ln-1; i>=0; i--){
            System.out.print(chars[i]+""+chars[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class MainFive {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Введите строку:");
            String str = sc.nextLine();

            int ln = str.length();
            char[] chars= str.toCharArray();



ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ln; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < ln; j++) {

            if (chars[i] == chars[j] && i != j) {
                count += 1;
            }

        }

        if (count > 0) {
            characters.add(chars[i]);
            count = 0;
        } else {
            characters.add(chars[i]);
            characters.add(chars[i]);
        }

    }

    // перевернутый вывод
    for (int i = characters.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(characters.get(i));
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, не правильно понял )
Тогда просто уберутся дублирующиеся символы, и из строки "abzca" получится  "aczba". 
А нужно чтобы получилось "acczzbba".

Comment: @Hacker Переделал